# Google links opens wrong pages

Tags: security, joomla

Our website has been recently hacked (Joomla 1.5, hosted on VPS). Attacker added few php scripts that were redirecting to some ad sites. We have cleaned everything (or at least we think we did), and now everything works as it should.

However, links on Google (or Yahoo) that are pointing to our web site are still trying to include these php scripts (and returns 404 as these are deleted now). Direct links from browser works as they should.

We have cleaned site 10 days ago, so I do not think that something is cached at Google servers. Re-indexing should be done by now.

To reproduce this behavior:

- Go to www.google.com
- type in "anitex socks"
- click any php link that starts with "anitexsocks.com"
- You will get "The requested URL /wp-includes/client.php was not found on this server" + 404 error
- Refresh page and everything works without issues

Why are only Google links making troubles?
Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you haven't deleted too many files?

Comment: On a related note, please be aware that Joomla 1.5 goes out of support this month and will no longer receive security updates http://developer.joomla.org/security.html  Time to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Thanks  Cheekysoft. Since the issue was caused by modified .htaccess file, is there a way that attacker can gain FTP or some other kind of access to files on web server by some Joomla related weaknes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the reason why this is happening, I installed a firefox add-on which blocks my browser's Referrer Header and then followed a Google link to your site and it worked fine. Then I disabled the add-on and the problem started occurring again.

This shows that there is still some malicious code running on your website which is checking all http requests to see if they come from Google (based on checking the HTTP Referrer header) and redirecting them to /wp-includes/client.php if they do,

To try to determine where this code may lie, try performing a recursive grep through all your www files on your server as well as your www configuration files,somewhere in there there must still be a reference to that client.php script, hopefully you can find and eliminate it.

That said, if it were my site and I knew a hacker had had free reign over my server to do whatever they wanted to it, I would not mess around with trying to undo the damage and would instead restore the most recent backup from before the site was hacked. You only have to miss one back door the hacker left in place and they can re-enter your site. After restoring backups, you should also upgrade/reconfigure the software they used to gain access in the first place so they can't simply rehack it in the same manner again.

Comment: I think what bdk said is a very good idea. I would also recommend updating to the most current version of Joomla 1.5 (or even better 2.5), uninstall any extensions you aren't using and upgrade the rest. Also consider installing something like this http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=jsecure to hide your administrator page.

Comment: Thanks bdk! .htaccess file was making the troubles!